# Device for people with advanced tremors and speech difficulties to type using feet and hand

Tags: accessibility, ux-designer, ux-integration, health, voice-control

Some older people are often full of tremors, including in their voice, and in their hands, but can still use their feet.

They can often also spell.

I was wondering whether anyone has designed a double pedal where you could scroll through letters with the left foot and select the letter with the left foot to write stuff on a screen.

These people could then communicate despite their developed disabilities.

They could also have a hand button to sound out what they typed with their feet on the screen (which could be simply an Android smartphone to which the button and pedals could connect via Bluetooth).

Wouldn't that be a good idea?

How else would you design a communicating system for people with tremors (who, perhaps, could not make themselves sounded clearly through their voice or could also not speak).

It would also be nice if they could train the system to sound with their natural voice while they had one or with their favorite intonation if they did not have a way to speak.

Would that be a good idea?

How would you design such a system for people with tremors they could not use their voice.

Please move my post to hardware recommendations if it already exists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different types of devices for people with tremors or even palsy. Regarding your specific question about foot controlled, you can see some examples below:

- https://thinksmartbox.com/user-stories/meet-lucia/
- https://www.trendhunter.com/trends/foot-mouse
- https://abilitynet.org.uk/factsheets/keyboard-and-mouse-alternatives-and-adaptations#simple-table-of-contents-10

Now, remember that accessibility devices are often customized and, as long as you have control of one part of your body, that device can be built (and probably has been). Think of [Stephen Hawking's wheelchair and communication device](https://www.scienceabc.com/innovation/stephen-hawking-cheek-communication-help-computer-speech-generating-device.html): he could only use a muscle on his cheek to control it. Building a foot device is trivial, especially when people who use their feet to communicate often use them as hands, allowing them to write, paint, or even play music.